# Determine the time complexity of my algorithm with python code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, greedy

my assignment asks me to come up with an algorithm and analyze the time complexity of my algorithm.The following code is what i wrote with python. a is any given value and b is set as default value 1. The goal is to find the minimum steps to let a=b by either double or increase b by 1(b+1). If my algorithm is correct, my while loop takes O(logn) and same as my for loop, so the final time complexity for my algorithm is O(logn)? Thank You!

```
a = 17
b = 1
count = []
while a !=1 :
    if a % 2 == 0:
        count.append(2)
        a = a/2
    else:
        count.append(1)
        a -= 1
count.reverse()
for i in count:
    if i == 2:
        b = 2*b
    else:
        b += 1
```

Comment: If you only need the number of steps, surely you only need `count.size()` and can simplify the whole thing (even though the time complexity won't change).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting *Introduction to Algorithms* (Cormen, page 25), 3rd Edition:

> The best notion for **input size** depends on the problem being studied. For many
> problems, such as sorting or computing discrete Fourier transforms, the most natural
> measure is the *number of items in the input*—for example, the array size n
> for sorting. For many other problems, such as multiplying two integers, the best
> measure of input size is the *total number of bits* needed to represent the input in
> ordinary binary notation.

The running time of your algorithm is `O(b)` where `b` is *total number of bits* of integer `a`.